# error TS2322: Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string' in angular

Tags: angular

I am converting string to number the PHP variable `gender`, but encountered an error:

> error TS2322: Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string' in
>   angular

Code:

```php
param = {
   id: '',
   username: '',
   fullName: '',
   gender: '',
   address: '',
   password: ''
};

saveUser(param: any) {
this.submitted = true;
if (this.UserForm.invalid) {
  return;
}
this.loading = true;
if (!this.ifEditUser) {
  this.param.gender = parseInt(this.param.gender, 10);
  this.userService.signinUser(param).subscribe((res: any) => {
    this.modal.close();
    switch (res.data) {
      case 1:
        this.toastr.error(res.message, 'Thông báo');
        break;
      case -2:
        this.toastr.warning(res.message, 'Thông báo');
        break;
      default:
        this.toastr.success(res.message, 'Thông báo');
    }

    this.resultTable._refreshDatasource(true, true);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the param obj where you have declared gender as a string, angular will throw an error as you are assigning a number to a string type.

```
param = {  gender: '', ...}
```

declare it as

```
param = {  gender: null, ...}
```

it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your id is defined as string in params = { id='', ...}. But i think you are assigning number to it. Hence the error